# loading up code snippet in emacs automatically

Tags: linux, emacs

I have a set of commonly used code bash script.  I want to load up these code snippet in emacs automatically upon creating a new file, how can this be setup?

Comment: Depending upon how elaborate you want your template, you may consider looking at the library skeletor https://github.com/chrisbarrett/skeletor.el   If you want something really simple, you could create a function that creates a buffer and then uses `insert-file-contents` to pull your code snippet.  You could also set up yasnippet -- https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet -- and have keyboard shortcuts to insert your snippets.  I also use a form file directory of larger snippets and I have a custom function that takes me to the forms directory and uses `insert-file-contents` on selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "snippet" in your question is a bit confusing, since it is often used to describe interactive insertion of bits of code while editing a document.

On the other hand, your description specifies "upon creating a new file", which makes me think you're really looking for some boilerplate to be automatically inserted into new files. In that case I would recommend the built-in [`auto-insert-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoInsertMode):

```
(auto-insert-mode)  ; Enable the feature globally

;;; Define what should get auto-inserted
(eval-after-load 'autoinsert
  '(define-auto-insert
     '("\\.sh\\'" . "Bash skeleton")
     '("Short description: "
       "#!/bin/bash\n\n"
       "More content...\n")))
```

Now when you create a new `.sh` file you should get a prompt asking if you want to "Perform Bash skeleton auto-insertion". If you always want to insert your template you can add

```
(setq auto-insert-query nil)
```

to skip the prompt.

If you would prefer to load your templates from a directory of files, do something like this instead:

```
(auto-insert-mode)
(setq auto-insert-directory "~/.emacs.d/templates/")
(define-auto-insert "\.sh" "bash-template.sh")
```

and create a file `~/.emacs.d/templates/bash-template.sh` to contain your template.

Comment: great code! now is it possible to read this code snippet from a file instead of inline?

Comment: also where would I be placing these initialization code?

Comment: @user121196, I've added a second example for loading templates from a directory. This code goes in your Emacs init file, which [might be `~/.emacs`, `~/.emacs.el`, or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).